# Is there a way to add data into a linking table of a many to many relationship in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have two tables `Documents` and `Groups`. I have a linking table called `DocumentsGroups` which contains both the documents and group ID.

I want to insert data into `DocumentsGroups`. I am getting a list of IDs of documents and and one ID of group and iterating through the list as below:

```
// List<DocumentIds> obj;
// groupId = 1;

var group = this._database.Groups.Single(d => d.Id == groupId);

// Looping through all the documents 
foreach(var doc in obj.DocumentsId)
{
    var document = this._database.Documents.Single(d => d.Id == doc);
    group.Documents.Add(document);
}
```

I am first finding the group object with the group ID of the commented out code. Then I am looping through the document list and grabbing an object of each document and then use it to add to the linking table but I get an error on the last line

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

`GroupDocuments` is a model which contains the IDs of the documents i am trying to add into the database so am receiving it from a view. I am indeed getting a single document object as I am looping through and i dont know how this error is coming. Does anyone know a work around?

Comment: Is `obj.DocumentsId` a collection?  You are trying to foreach over it.

Comment: Also, in your code snippet `obj` isn't initialized.

Comment: Yes its a collection i just added it as a comment to show its a collection. It contains the IDs of documents hence am looping through it

Comment: Does that mean `obj` is a list of lists?  What's the purpose of including the commented code `List<DocumentIds> obj`.  How can you call `obj.DocumentsId` if `obj` is itself a list?  This code will not run as written.

Comment: My bad. i did not include the full code. In short GroupDocuments is a model and inside it is the collection of the IDs. Making sense now? I edited the question also

Comment: Please post the code for your three entities: Documents, Groups and DocumentsGroups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to include documents before adding or create a list

```
var group = _database.Groups.Where(d => d.Id == groupId).Include(i=>i.Documents).FirstOrDefault();

if (group!=null)
{
   if (group.Documents==null) group.Documents=new List<Document>();

// and only now you can start adding
foreach(var doc in obj.DocumentsId)
{
    var document = _database.Documents.Where(d => d.Id == doc).Single();
 
    group.Documents.Add(document);
}
_database.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: This solved the issue. I was not checking for null first. Thank you